How to convert a CUDA ipc memory handle to a PyTorch tensor?
I do not know how to convert an ipc_mem_handle to a PyTorch tensor directly.
ipc_mem_handle = drv.IPCMemoryHandle(h)
# GPU to CPU numpy
result = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.float32)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(result, ipc_mem_handle)
# CPU numpy to tensor
tensor = torch.from_numpy(result)
param.data = tensor

The only way I found is copying to a host Numpy array, and then creating a PyTorch tensor from that.
